# How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cos{(nx)}$ does not uniformly converge in $\left( 0,2\pi \right)$ with the conditions below?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real numbers such that:
>
> - $a_n \ge 0$
> - $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: a_n \ge a_{n+1}$
> - $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =0$
> - $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } a_n =\infty $
>
> Consider the sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cos{(nx)}$ . Prove:
>
> 1. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cos{(nx)}$ uniformly converges in $\left[ \frac{\pi}{2},\pi \right]$
> 2. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n \cos{(nx)}$ does not uniformly converge in $\left( 0,2\pi \right)$

---

I only need help with 2 (I already solved 1). I'm trying to solve it for almost a day now. I'd appreciate if you could explain how to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Since $\sum a_n = \infty$, you will have trouble at $x=0$.  This suggests we look at small neighborhoods $(0,\delta)$ for the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sum a_n=\infty$, then we have $$\exists\epsilon>0, \forall N, \exists m, n, (m>n\ge N), \Longrightarrow \sum_{k=n}^{m}a_k\ge\frac \epsilon{\cos(1)}$$

Now, let $x=\frac1{m}$,

$$\sum_{k=n}^{m}a_k\cos(kx)=\sum_{k=n}^{m}a_k\cos\left(\frac k{m}\right)\ge \sum_{k=n}^{m}a_k\cos(1)\ge\epsilon$$

hence, it is not uniformly convergent on $(0,2\pi)$

Comment: The negation of the Cauchy criterion says there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N$, there exist $n,m$ with $m>n\geqslant N$ such that $\sum_{k=n}^m a_k > \epsilon/\cos(1)$.  Since $a_k >0$ this holds with $n = N$ but you don't know that $m = 2N$ works.  If it happens that $m \leqslant 2N$ then of course you can set the upper limit to $2N$ but you may have $m > 2N$.

Comment: Thank you, it is fixed @RRL

Comment: (1) Thank you.
(2) How did you think to use Cauchy criterion? is this something that helps in questions like this?
(3) You showed $\sum_{k=n}^{m}a_k\cos(kx)=\sum_{k=n}^{m}a_k\cos\left(\frac k{m}\right)\ge \sum_{k=n}^{m}a_k\cos(1)\ge\epsilon$ and that says that there is no convergence at all of the sum $\sum_{k=n}^{m}a_k\cos(kx)$ in $(0,2\pi)$ because $x=\frac{1}{m} \in (0,2\pi)$?
(4) Again thank you so much!

Comment: You are very welcome! We want to show it is not uniform, namely $\ge \dots\ge\dots\ge\epsilon$. To fill in those $\dots$ we need a lower bound, and $\cos(t)$ is decreasing when $0<t<1$, so I choose to use Cauchy, since it has a truncated end-point, namely the m-th term. In this case, we can manipulate $x$. @Lior